# Typescript types for two objects that combine to form an object type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

E.g.:

```
type Obj = {
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c: number,
}

function outer<T extends Partial<Obj>>(obj1: T) {
  return function inner(obj2: Omit<Obj, keyof T>) {
    const obj: Obj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };
    console.log(obj);
  }
}
```

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigbwFBSgQwFxQB2ArgLZwQBOANFlHASeVbdgMaNkU0YC+GGAGbFCbYAEsA9oSiTiwKgB4AKlAgAPBYQAmAZygAFHJQk4ANovgIAfNYAUkxAEYCygJTo6lCMGKUZwqIS0lDihIRUDogATAQwpOLAlojUUADWECCSglDK1h6Y2OzSusCyiHGIKOhQAHT1jghOqfW1jdFQvADcdMWEupJmELVmkgDmUQhuPdj8vEA

I want to ensure that `obj1` and `obj2` will combine to match the `Obj` type. It doesn't matter which of the keys are in `obj1` and which keys are in `obj2`. It doesn't matter if some keys overlap, but it'll be nice to avoid overlapping.

However, the code above doesn't work. I get `Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.`. Is it possible to get this working?

Comment: I don't think so, your best bet may be to just cast it: `const obj: Obj = {...obj1, ...obj2} as Obj;`. It seems like you've constructed it in such a way that `obj` will always be "complete", but TypeScript does not have enough information based on the generics to infer it 100%.

Comment: I wanted to use TS to ensure I don't accidentally leave out a property. It'll be nice if it could also detect duplicate properties

Comment: What do you mean “leave out a property”? The way you e constructed the function and types that seems to be impossible.